# Where should CentOS users get /usr/share/virtio-win/drivers for virt-v2v?

Tags: centos, vmware-esx, kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I need to migrate a number of virtual machines from VMware ESX to CentOS 6 KVM hypervisors. Ultimately, I wrote an RPM spec file that solved my problem at https://github.com/fasrc/virtio-win/blob/master/virtio-win.spec but I'm not sure if there's another RPM in base CentOS or EPEL (something standard) I should be using instead.

Originally, I was getting this "No root device found in this operating system image" error when attemting to migrate a Window 2008 VM. . .

```
[root@kvm01b ~]# virt-v2v -ic 'esx://my-vmware-hypervisor.example.com/' \
-os transferimages --network default my-vm
virt-v2v: No root device found in this operating system image.
```

. . . but I solved this with a simply `yum install libguestfs-winsupport` since [the docs](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/V2V_Guide/sect-V2V_Guide-Configuration_Changes-Configuration_Changes_for_Windows_Virtual_Machines.html) say:

> If you attempt to convert a virtual machine using NTFS without the
>   libguestfs-winsupport package installed, the conversion will fail.

Next I got an error about missing drivers for Windows 2008. . .

```
[root@kvm01b ~]# virt-v2v -ic 'esx://my-vmware-hypervisor.example.com/' \
-os transferimages --network default my-vm
my-vm_my-vm: 100% [====================================]D
virt-v2v: Installation failed because the following files referenced in
the configuration file are required, but missing:
/usr/share/virtio-win/drivers/amd64/Win2008
```

. . . and I resolved this by grabbing an iso from Fedora at http://alt.fedoraproject.org/pub/alt/virtio-win/latest/ as recommended by http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers and building an RPM from it with this spec file: https://github.com/fasrc/virtio-win/blob/master/virtio-win.spec

Now, virt-v2v exits without error:

```
[root@kvm01b ~]# virt-v2v -ic 'esx://my-vmware-hypervisor.example.com/' \
-os transferimages --network default my-vm
my-vm_my-vm: 100% [====================================]D
virt-v2v: my-vm configured with virtio drivers.
[root@kvm01b ~]#
```

Now, my question is, rather that the [virtio-win RPM from the spec file I wrote](https://github.com/fasrc/virtio-win/blob/master/virtio-win.spec), is there some other more standard RPM in base CentOS or EPEL that will resolve the error above?

Here's a bit more detail about my setup:

```
[root@kvm01b ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
[root@kvm01b ~]# rpm -q virt-v2v
virt-v2v-0.8.3-5.el6.x86_64
```

See also [Bug 605334 – VirtIO driver for windows does not show specific OS: Windows 7, Windows 2003](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=605334)

Comment: See also [CentOS-virt] Where should CentOS users get /usr/share/virtio-win/drivers for virt-v2v? - http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-virt/2012-June/002927.html

Comment: I don't have an answer but I'm working on this too...will probably just end up digging up our Redhat license/login to get the official RPM, because virt-v2v seems to rely heavily on exact file locations. I end up with this error having just copied some files around from the ISO. `# virt-v2v -ic esx://10.0.0.10/?no_verify=1 -o libvirt -os virtimages win7convert win7basev1_convert_vmwarewin7-Windows7Base9-v1_esx: 100% [=============================================================================================]D 0h23m04s cp: cp: cp: cannot stat \`/sysroot/transferOHZCOb/usr/sh\``

Answer (score 1):

The fedora project VirtIO drivers are the way to go for any KVM implementation on any linux. There for what you did is the correct approach.